# Accessing variable name vs value in vim

Tags: vim

I came across the following behavior in vim which seemed a bit unexpected to me:

```
:let word="nnoremap"
:h word
```

I thought that it would open the help for `nnoremap` but instead it opens help for `word`. Could someone please explain this behavior to me (or perhaps point to where it's documented in vim help)? What would be the way to reference the variable value? For example, now I'm doing:

```
:execute(printf(':h %s', word))
```

Is there a more straightforward way to do this, such as something like (in pseudo-syntax):

```
:h &word
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:help` doesn't take an expression, but a tag (part). I guess `:h :h` converts the subject.

Thus if you want the help on a variable... as usual, `:execute` is the solution.

```
exe 'h '.word
```

Comment: just to make sure I'm understanding correctly, when you say it doesn't take an expression, does that mean it takes, basically, an 'unquoted literal' ?

Comment: And one more thing -- is there a way to directly reference the variable value of a name, without using `exe`, or that's not possible in vim?

Comment: I guess you can see the `{subject}` as an _unquoted literal_. See [`:h :help`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/helphelp.txt.html#%3ahelp) everything is explained there.

Comment: In a few contexts (that I don't remember exactly), we can use `:somecommand {variable}` instead of `:exe 'somecommand '.variable`, but it's not possible with `:h` as almost any character is used literally by `:help`. Read the help.

Comment: @David542 you were already doing this, actually: your command parses as `:execute (printf(':h %s', word))`, and the outer parens are superfluous (there is an execute command and an execute function, and the do different things). The printf is better than string concatenation, i think, but in this case not needed: `:execute 'help' word` works because of a quirk of the execute command